# How do I pass data from my Parent Component to Child Component in Angular?

Tags: angular

This is my Parent Component, and I want to pass data like distinct headings(which is message in here) to each of its Child Component. How do I do that??

Parent:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <h1 class="title">Whatever</h1>
            <p class="subtitle">Nothing.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="cardContainer">
                <app-cards [message]=message></app-cards>
                <app-cards [message]=message></app-cards>
                <app-cards [message]=message></app-cards>
                <app-cards [message]=message></app-cards>               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child:

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="bg-text">
        <div class="title">{{message}}</div>
        <h6>Obviously, you are important</h6>
        <div class="cardButtons">
            <a href="" class="link link1">Health</a>
            <a href="" class="link link2">Travel</a>
            <a href="" class="link link3">Accident</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Parent Child - Pass data to child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947291/angular-parent-child-pass-data-to-child-component)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you elaborate on your question? The code you have written looks fine. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

May be following solution would help you :)

**ParentTemplate:**

```
<div>
    <app-child [message]="messageFromParent"></app-child>
</div>
```

**ParentComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit { 

  messageFromParent : string;  
 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {   

    this.messageFromParent = "Hellow world!";
    
  }    
}
```

**ChildTemplate:**

```
<div>
    {{message}}
</div>
```

**ChildComponent:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() message: string;    
 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {   
    
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set message as input in Child.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cards',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html'  
})

export class Childcomponent implements OnInit{
 @Input() message : any;

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() { 
  console.log(this.message );
}
}
```

Parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit { 

  message : string; // Message From parent  
 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {   

    this.message = "TEST CASE"; // Message From parent
    
  }    
}
```

Parent.component.html

```
 <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="cardContainer">
                // {{message}} from Parent will send as @Input message of Child 
                <app-cards [message]={{message}}></app-cards>                              
            </div>
 </div>
```

You will receive data on the Parent Part. For further more details you can refer these links :
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs  and
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-passing-data-child-component/

Comment: Okay, but I have already written this @Input() in my child class.
this is what I have in my parent class.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'section2',
  templateUrl: './section2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./section2.component.css']
})
export class Section2Component implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }
  message="hello world";
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```